# How to use wolfram to solve induction problem

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, induction

I need to solve this problem with induction k in natural numbers

So how I write this problem in wolfram Engine ?

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Some techniques here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144096/how-to-represent-fx-y-xk-logy-x-as-a-summation-of-the-form-fx

Comment: I would be happy if someone will learn to me how to make this question in wolfram

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is correct.  Does the leading point mean something?

[image]

Comment: I want to use the wolfram for solve this problem not by myself, because I have many questions and I just started a course in the university, do you have an idea how to use induction in wolfram that will improve this sentence?

Comment: You will get better answers if you ask here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/